# Same php variable in different spots

Tags: php, html

Just want to know what will hapen if i will set a variable in some line at the php file and than try to get the value in a different php script but in the same html code.
Will it be this value or i have to use it in the same script.

Lets say -

```
<html>
<head>
<?php 
     $a = "Hello";
?>

<\head>
<body>
<?
     echo $a;
?>
<\body>
<\html>
```

Will it be - "Hello"?

Comment: Why not try it and see what happens? :) You will probably learn more about it by trying in this case then getting a one or two word answer.

Comment: Why cant you try and post answer for all.

Comment: And on that note, if you provide an answer yourself and explain it as best you can, I will certainly vote it up.

Comment: @Fluffeh You are right. My bad.

Answer (score 1):

You have said 'In a different PHP script'.

That's not quite how PHP works - the php 'script' is all of the php that is executed when a page is requested.

But back to your question, think of it this way:

```
<?php
```

says "Here is some php code".

```
?>
```

says "This is **not** php code".

It's like talking to 2 people at once - the other person still knows what you're talking about when you turn back to them.

I agree with the comments though - these sort of things are very easy to check yourself :)